# No se asigna el dato

Tags: javascript, fetch

Hago multiples consultas mediante `Promise.All` y al final retorno la data. Esta funcion la uso en un constructor y mediante el `then()` , asigno el valor a una propiedad de clase, sin embargo, no funciona. ¿A qué se debe?

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(){
        this.specialtiesAux = [];
            
        load_specialties("Gyne")
        .then(data => this.specialtiesAux = data[1]);
            
        console.log(this.specialtiesAux)
    }
}
```

Hago un `console.log()` y me arroja el arreglo vacio pero si lo hago dentro del `then()`, si me arroja los datos correctos. ¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El comportamiento es el esperado. Podés revisar la [documentación de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) sobre esto.

Básicamente, cuando vos hacés:

```javascript
        load_specialties("Gyne")
        .then(data => this.specialtiesAux = data[1]);
```

el argumento del `then` queda para ejecutarse de manera asíncrona. Por esto, el `console.log` inmediatamente después no ve ningún cambio. Si metés la promesa devuelta por esto en una variable y la logueás, vas a ver que el estado de la promesa es "Pendiente" inicialmente.

Esto es como cuando dejás una función con un timer. No vas a ver los side effects hasta que se ejecute.

Si logueas desde el then(), entonces estás logueando desde la ejecución asíncrona. Eso te dice que la promesa se está aceptando y que la función trabaja como querés.

Espero haberme explicado bien. El link que te dejé te puede resolver con un poco más de detalle.